# Unable to insert New Line in a string of the vuetify dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I attempted to insert a new line in the string which is the Vuetify dialog text by using \n in the string. But it does not work.

Here is the code for the function that calls Vuetify dialog

```js
handleDialog()
{
    this.dialogHeading = "Clearing all component data"
    this.dialogText = "Do you really want to clear all the component data?\nThis will clear the components except the pressure and composition basis!"
    this.dialogBtn1 = "Cancel"
    this.dialogBtn2 = "Yes"
    this.isDialog = true
  
}
```

And here is the code for displaying the Vuetify dialog

```js
<v-layout row wrap  >
   <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
       <v-dialog v-model="isDialog" persistent max-width=400>
          <v-card>
              <v-card-title  class=" error title white--text 
              darken-2 font-weight-bold">{{dialogHeading}}
              </v-card- title>
              <v-card-text>{{dialogText}}</v-card-text>
              <v-card-text v-if="dialogText2">{{dialogText2}}
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions   >
                <v-btn  v-if="dialogBtn1" flat class=
                "align-content-center d-flex mx-auto" dark 
                color="red darken-1 font-weight-bold" 
                text 
                @click="clearDialog('no')">{{dialogBtn1}}</v-btn>
                <v-btn  v-if="dialogBtn2" flat 
                class="align-content-center d-flex mx-auto 
                font-weight-bold" dark color="green darken-1" 
                text @click="clearDialog('yes')">{{dialogBtn2}}
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
   </v-flex>
            
</v-layout>
```

I've tried using '\n' .

I need the second sentence in the next line

Here is the screenshot of the result that I get
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `<br/>` tag instead of `\n` in order to go to the next line and use `v-html` directive to render that string :

```
  this.dialogText = "Do you really want to clear all the component data?<br/>This will clear the components except the pressure and composition basis!"
```

template:

```
  <v-card-text v-html="dialogText"></v-card-text>
```

Answer (score 7):

One way to achieve this would be to wrap each line in a block-level element such as a `<div>` within the template. The original string could be split on newlines and iterated accordingly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data () {
    return {
      dialogText: 'First line\nSecond line'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@3.9.97/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>Title</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <div v-for="(text, index) in dialogText.split('\n')" :key="index">
          {{ text }}
        </div>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

This retains the default escaping behaviour that would be lost using `v-html`.

Comment: Thank you skirtle for taking time to respond to my question. I shall let you know how it turned out once I have checked this.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle. This is a good way because it reduces the chances of html injection compared to v-html.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use div, like this:

```
<v-card-text>
      <div>{{ dialogText }}</div>
      <div>Whitsunday Island, Whitsunday Islands</div>
</v-card-text>
```

[The code is from vuetify card docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#media-with-text)

Answer (score 1):

you can put `text-pre-wrap` on your element's class and just use regular `\n` breaks or even template strings with line breaks in them:

```
<v-card-text class="text-pre-wrap">
    {{dialogText}}
</v-card-text>

<!-- The same as -->
<v-card-text class="text-pre-wrap">
    {{
        `Do you really want to clear all the component data?\nThis will clear the components except the pressure and composition basis!`
    }}
</v-card-text>

<!-- The same as -->
<v-card-text class="text-pre-wrap">
    {{
        `Do you really want to clear all the component data?
        This will clear the components except the pressure and composition basis!`
    }}
</v-card-text>
```