# How to effectivly break line of the content inside a vuetify component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi i'm triying to break line at the content inside a vuetify component but I haven't success. I need help to understand why, see the code below

```
<v-list-item-content style="word-break: break-word" class="kbDarkBlueText--text d-block" v-else>
                    {{ longText}}
</v-list-item-content>
```

I also try to apply the class text-wrap and the style break-all but none success.
pd: html element is setted to word-break:normal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945915

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621742/2541658

Comment: @Mohsen: your links are not related to OP's problem with v-list-items. See my answer below instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `v-list-item-title` and `v-list-item-subtitle` avoid line breaks and cut overflowing text with an ellipsis instead. This hides long texts.

To change this behavior, you can manipulate the CSS like this:

```
<style scoped>
* /deep/ .v-list-item__subtitle {
  white-space: normal;
}
</style>
```

Source: [wrap-word does not work on v-list-item-title/subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769385/wrap-word-does-not-work-on-v-list-item-title-subtitle)

I'm using scoped CSS here to apply this only to the component you use it in. As the CSS is scoped, the `/deep/`  selector is required. See [docs on scoped CSS in Vue](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html).

If you want to apply the behavior globally, you can remove the `scoped` property and the `/deep/` selector.